# Npoco new Database fails with "Value cannot be null"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, npoco

I am trying to update an MVC project from NPoco 3 to NPoco 5.

I could no longer use:

`using var db = new Database("DB");`

so I changed it to:

`using var db = new Database(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString, DatabaseType.SqlServer2012, SqlClientFactory.Instance);`

and I even tried:

`using var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);`
`conn.Open();`

`using var db = new Database(conn);`

But no matter what I try,
I just get

**Value cannot be null**

> [Exception: No database type found for the type string specified: 'SqlServerDatabaseType'. Make sure the relevant assembly NPoco.SqlServer is referenced.]

> NPoco.DynamicDatabaseType.MakeSqlServerType(String type) +194

> NPoco.DatabaseType.Resolve(String typeName, String providerName) +298

> NPoco.Database..ctor(DbConnection connection, DatabaseType dbType, Nullable`1 isolationLevel, Boolean enableAutoSelect) +111

How do I open a Database connection in version 5 of NPoco?  It doesn't seem to work at all.

(I did notice that I am building to .NET Framework 4.6.1, which is also what NPoco 5 says it works on.)

Thanks for any help if anyone else has seen this.

Comment: After looking through the source code, there are the following DatabaseTypes: Firebird, MySql, Oracle, OracleManaged, PostgreSql, SQLite. I don't see how it could work to try to get the type of DatabaseType.SqlServer2012, which tries to find a type which does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

In a change from Version 3 to Version 5, you must also now add the NuGet package NPoco.SqlServer.